# Performantly determine symmetry of highly dimensional array

Tags: arrays, typescript

I'm working with 6 dimensional arrays of strings `string[][][][][][]`. I need to determine if two given arrays are equivalent by some symmetry. Here's an example of arrays that by my definition of symmetry are symmetrical.

```js
const a: string[][] = [["a", "b"], ["a", "c", "c"]];
const b: string[][] = [["c", "a", "c"], ["a", "b"]];
const isSymmetrical: boolean = determineIfSymmetrical(a, b);
// isSymmetrical: true
```

Symmetry might be the wrong word for this but what I'm looking for is that there is a reordering of the arrays that exists in which the arrays would be identical in structure and contents.

I currently have a solution which uses a large number of calls to `JSON.stringify` to convert intermediate arrays to strings and then use the `.sort()` method on each of them. It works but can't be the most efficient way.

This is my current inefficient solution:

```js
type MultiDimensionalArray = string[][][][][][];

const sortArrays = <Element extends unknown>(
  a: Element[],
  b: Element[]
): number => {
  const aString = JSON.stringify(a);
  const bString = JSON.stringify(b);
  if (aString > bString) {
    return 1;
  } else if (aString === bString) {
    return 0;
  }
  return -1;
};

const convertToStructure = (
  array: MultiDimensionalArray,
  transform: (input: string) => string
): string => {
  return JSON.stringify(
    array
      .map((a) =>
        a
          .map((a) =>
            a
              .map((a) =>
                a
                  .map((a) =>
                    a
                      .map((a) => a.map((a) => transform(a)).sort())
                      .sort(sortArrays)
                  )
                  .sort(sortArrays)
              )
              .sort(sortArrays)
          )
          .sort(sortArrays)
      )
      .sort(sortArrays)
  );
};

export const assertArraySymmetry = (
  a: MultiDimensionalArray,
  b: MultiDimensionalArray,
  transform: (input: string) => string
): boolean =>
  convertToStructure(a, transform) === convertToStructure(b, transform);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a very neat example that also supports any level of dimensionality through recursion:

```js
export const determineIfSymmetrical = <
  MultiDimensionalArray extends (MultiDimensionalArray | string)[]
>(
  a: MultiDimensionalArray,
  b: MultiDimensionalArray
): boolean => {
  const isStringArray = a.some((aElement) => typeof aElement === "string");
  if (isStringArray) {
    const aTransformed = (a as string[])
      .map(transform || ((input) => input))
      .sort();
    const bTransformed = (b as string[])
      .map(transform || ((input) => input))
      .sort();
    return aTransformed.sort().every((aString, index) => {
      const bString = bTransformed[index];
      return aString === bString;
    });
  }
  return a.every((subA) => {
    return b.some((subB) =>
      determineIfSymmetrical(
        subA as MultiDimensionalArray,
        subB as MultiDimensionalArray
      )
    );
  });
};
```